# 2 Layouts for JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border-layout, boxlayout

I am making a gui for a program and it uses `JPanels` to do so. I have 2 `JPanels`. The first one contains a `JLabel`, and `JTextField`. The second one contains a `JLabel` and `JTextField`. I need both of those at the bottom of the screen, one on top of the other. I tried `BorderLayout.SOUTH` but one of the `Panels` overwrites the other. And if I use `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` then they are not centered or at the bottom. How would I do this?

EDIT: I fixed it.  I forgot to set a border layout when I added the panel to the frame.  So I fixed it.

Comment: In the future, please show your pertinent code relevant to your question. That will save us much grief and waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: nest JPanels

Create a 3rd JPanel, one that uses BoxLayout oriented to BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS, add your 2 JPanels to this, and then add this third JPanel to the main GUI (which hopefully uses BorderLayout) to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END position.

---

For example, my [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample extends JPanel {
   public LayoutExample() {
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
      panel1.add(new JTextField(10));
      panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 1"));

      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.add(new JLabel("Label 2"));
      panel2.add(new JTextField(10));
      panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 2"));

      JPanel boxLayoutUsingPanel = new JPanel();
      boxLayoutUsingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxLayoutUsingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      boxLayoutUsingPanel.add(panel1);
      boxLayoutUsingPanel.add(panel2);
      boxLayoutUsingPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("BoxLayout Panel"));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Main BorderLayout GUI"));
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(400, 200)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(boxLayoutUsingPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LayoutExample mainPanel = new LayoutExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

If still stuck, create and post your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It partially worked. It made the text fields not full screen but they are still not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JoelButenhoff: see and run my example code above. If this doesn't fix it, then edit your question and post your own [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).